# Pre select options from list dynamically

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jquery-plugins, jstl

I'm currently teaching myself some coding and building a small web application for practice where users can have roles.
It's based on Spring MVC.
Users can be edited. 
What I want to do is that when the user profile comes up it will list you the user's roles, with the roles he already has as selected and all the available roles unselected.

I'm also using the jquery multiselect.js plugin for a nice separated look of the selected and unselected items.

I'm currently adding two attributes to my requestmethod in the controller:

allroles and userroles

I thought that using some JSTL tags would work to generade the select list:

```
<c:forEach items="${allroles}" var="role">
<c:forEach items="${userroles}" var="userrole">
<form:option value="${role.id}" selected="${role.name == userrole.name ? 'selected' : ''}">${role.name}</form:option>
</c:forEach></c:forEach>
```

Well, this works fine if the user has only one current role.
But once he has 2 or more the options will appear doubled or tripled [...] in the list, which breaks the select.
That makes sense since it's two nested foreach loops, but I just want it to go through allroles and check which roles equal to the roles on userroles and mark them as selected if so.

I'm kinda stuck at the moment here, can anyone please tell me if it's even possible to do this with JSTL and/or what would be the correct or a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have overridden the `equals` method for the role class and you are using EL 2.2+, you can simplify this markup to:

```
<c:forEach items="${ allroles }" var="role">
    <form:option value="${ role.id }" selected="${ userroles.contains(role) ? 'selected' : ''}">
        ${role.name}
    </form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

This should solve your duplication problem.

Comment: Thanks, worked great... I also learned how to override the equals method ;-)

 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other == this || (other instanceof Role && this.getName().equals(((Role) other).getName()))) {
            return true;
        }
  return false;      
    }